# Handling different ConnectionStates before opening SqlConnection

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

If you need to open a SqlConnection before issuing queries, can you simply handle all non-Open ConnectionStates in the same way?  For example:

```
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
```

I read somewhere that for ConnectionState.Broken the connection needs to be closed before its re-opened.  Does anyone have experience with this?  Thanks-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx

Broken connection state does need to be closed and reopened before eligible for continued use.

Edit: Unfortunately closing a closed connection will balk as well. You'll need to test the ConnectionState before acting on an unknown connection. Perhaps a short switch statement could do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't directly answering your question, but the best practice is to open and close a connection for every access to the database.  ADO.NET connection pooling ensures that this performs well.  It's particularly important to do this in server apps (e.g. ASP.NET), but I would do it even in a WinForms app that accesses the database directly.

Example:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
   connection.Open();
   // ... do your stuff here

}  // Connection is disposed and closed here, even if an exception is thrown
```

In this way you never need to check the connection state when opening a connection.

Comment: You should not wait for the GC to close and dispose a connection. You should explicitly close a connection once you're done using it.

Comment: The using statement ensures the connection is closed, even if an exception is thrown.  It doesn't wait for the GC to close it.

Comment: This using pattern is how all data access should look.  You'll never leak connections this way.  Joe, I would also add "using (SqlCommand command..." inside the using for SqlConnection, and recommend a constant for the query string to make sure it always comes from the same pool.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it the same way.  I was getting numerous connection state == broken while using IE9.  There is something fundamentally wrong with IE9 in this regard since no other browser had this issue of broken connection states after 5 or 6 updates to the database tables.  So I use object context.  So basically just close it and re-open it.

I have this code before all my reads and updates in the business logic layer:

```
if (context.Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Broken)
{
    context.Connection.Close();
    context.Connection.Open();
}
```