# Calling Close on SqlConnection that might not be open or closed

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient

The answers to these two questions are very close to answering my own, but they don't quite get there.

- [Are Open and Closed only relevant values of ConnectionState enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246316/are-open-and-closed-only-relevant-values-of-connectionstate-enumeration)
- [Handling different ConnectionStates before opening SqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103532/handling-different-connectionstates-before-opening-sqlconnection)

Now that I know `SqlConnection` has more states than just open and closed, I wonder if I need to do this when closing a connection that **isn't inside a using statement**:

```
switch (_transactionConnection.State)
{
    case ConnectionState.Broken: /*??*/ ; break;
    case ConnectionState.Closed: ; break;
    case ConnectionState.Connecting: /*??*/ ; break;
    case ConnectionState.Executing: /*??*/ ; break;
    case ConnectionState.Fetching: /*??*/ ; break;
    default: _transactionConnection.Close(); break;                         
}
```

`SqlConnection _transactionConnection` is not inside a `using` statement because I need to Start, Commit and Rollback a transaction from outside this class. This class implements `IDisposable` and the switch statement lives in `Dispose(bool disposing)`

MSDN says that states other than open and closed are for future versions of the product, but @Charlie says reflector shows the other states are in use.

Can anyone tell me what should replace the `/*??*/`? (I expect that my final switch statement will handle the Open and Closed cases explicitly and if `/*??*/` is the same for the other states, that would be my default case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're implementing this in Dispose(), I think I would simply call `_transactionConnection.Dispose();` and let the SqlConnection class do whatever it feels is appropriate. I would avoid calling `Close()` here, because while it's true that currently SqlConnection.Dispose basically just closes it, that may change in the future.

Comment: If this code wasn't inside Dispose, then ... it's hard to say; I would want review the way you're using these components, because without more information about your requirements I would suspect you were on the wrong track, implementation-wise.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm happy with Dispose in this scenario. And since `using` calls Dispose anyway, that must be how SqlConnections are closed when people open them in the preferred way.